# Compare two interfaces using "is"

Tags: actionscript-3, interface, comparison, flash-builder

I am not sure if I am missing something here. I would like to compare two classes that uses the same `interface`. Is this possible? I understand that the `is` operator compares classes, but is there any similar function when you use interfaces?

```
// works
var effect1 : CrazyEffect = new CrazyEffect();
var effect2 : SaneEffect = new SaneEffect();

trace(effect1 is effect2) // false

// does not work
var effect1 : ISoundEffect = new CrazyEffect();
var effect2 : ISoundEffect = new SaneEffect();

trace(effect1 is effect2)
```

**1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type ISoundEffect to an unrelated type Class.**

Comment: Are `CrazyEffect` and `SaneEffect` both set up as implementations of ISoundEffect in their class definitions?

Comment: Yes. Both classes implements the same interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the differences between concepts of a class and of an object. The former is a data type whereas the latter is a runtime instance of it, a variable. **`is`** operator can not compare one variable to another.

According to [language reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#is)

> **is** Operator
>
> Evaluates whether an object is compatible with a specific **data type,
>   class, or interface**. Use the is operator instead of the instanceof
>   operator for **type comparisons**. You can also use the is operator to
>   check whether an object implements an interface.

In other words, compiler expects the first operand to be a **variable** whereas the second operand should be a **type identifier**.

```
var sample:String = "Object is an instance of a class.";
     ^^^    ^^^
variable    type identifier
```

However `effect2` is not a type identifier but a variable. Hence the error message.

Unfortunately there is no generic operator to test for interface commonality. The only alternative is:

```
trace((s is ISoundEffect) && (t is ISoundEffect));
```

---

### Update

Checking whether objects are instances of a same class can be done by comparing class names:

```
if (getQualifiedClassName(effect1) == getQualifiedClassName(effect2)) {
   // true
}
```

For in depth discussion see [Get the class used to create an object instance in AS3](http://joshblog.net/2009/05/11/retrieve-the-class-used-to-instantiate-an-object-in-as3/)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think I will add a getter to the interface to be able to use `(effect1.type == effect2.type)` instead.

Comment: I looked at your code again. It it not doing what I intend to do. I already know that both classes are using the interface. I want to see if effect1 and effect2 is the same class.

Comment: Then you should look at `getQualifiedClassName()` and `getQualifiedSuperClassName()` I guess.

Comment: @Mattias - In that case what frankhermes suggests is correct. See update.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it will work with getQualifiedClassName, there's a better method to check whether two objects are instances of the same class:

```
a['constructor'] === b['constructor']
```

getQualifiedClassName is very slow and CPU intensive. Since the above code just compares property values it is lightning fast. And yes, `constructor` IS a property of every object, however FB will complain if you try to access it using dot-notation, that's why I use dynamic property access.

Comment: Interesting! I added a getter (`String`) to compare the types instead. Works fine. But I did not know that you could access `constructor`. +1

Comment: Ahh, ECMAScript. Another interesting fact, every data type in AS3 actually has a `prototype` property too. You can add properties/methods to any class or even override the base `Object.toString` implementation if you want, and it'll affect all existing sub-classes, but it's highly un-recommended.

Comment: @Peter: Ssssssh.... That's something that should stay secret, we REALLY don't want to go back to the ol' days of AS2 monkey patching :)